# Replacing Tactile Switches

Tags: soldering

1. Is there a specific way to connect/solder tactile switches?
2. Will I risk damaging the remote if I solder the wrong way?

I am trying to replace the ones on the remote with a 6 pin tact switch. 6 pin tact switch has LED on it so i guess the ones on the middle(straight pins) are for the LED?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to test the switch with a multimeter to figure out which pin is which. Don't proceed until you have done that.

Comment: "*i guess the ones on the middle(straight pins) are for the LED?*" Why are you guessing? Did you buy switches without a datasheet? (This is usually a bad idea.)

Comment: VTC - Whilst this question is interesting and has even garnered an answer it is still off topic here. This site is about design; not repair and replacement of electronics devices.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who looked and took the time to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first observation shows that your switch seems to be a through hole switch, but the switch you are replacing is surface mount.

As others have said, don't "guess" the pinout - consult the datasheet. If you don't have one (as can happen if you have the switches from a small electronics store, or if you purchase them from a HAM-swap meet or from surplus sales), you should use a multimeter to confirm the pinout. The way you can do this is to just probe the pins with in continuity test mode on your meter, and then press the switch. Sometimes the pins will be shorted no matter if the switch is depressed or not.

Once you figured that out, you do the same with the switches you try to replace. Ofcourse, if they are broken, they might not make contact, which can make it a bit harder. If this is the case, you can try looking at the PCB to see if only two pins are connected to any traces. If so, this will be the switch contacts.